# tranisition from iphone to ipad nibs

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder, nib

i am wondering how its possible to have an iphone nib that has some uitextfields and some labels to be automatically repotitioned if the device is an ipad. (i dont want a second nib) im trying to get my iphone nib to autoresize in the middle of the screen if the device is an ipad so that all the text fields and buttons arent placed in the top left corner. I tired using the autosizing masks however they wouldnt work for the textfield(im not sure why exactly the horizontal autoresize didnt work) is there any way i can do this without making a new nib if the device is an ipad?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this would work, but you might try using a view that's the same size as the iPhone screen, set the autosize flags on that to keep it in the middle of the screen without stretching it, then put all of your views inside that view.

Comment: i am trying that however it doesnt work :( i used both the "box" stretching autoresizing and the exterior anchors however none of the produced any good results. if i have that view in an iphone it shows as an ipad...